# How can I access UD fields in Epicor10 business objects outside of Epicor?

Tags: c#, epicorerp

In Epicor 9 it was fairly easy to open Visual Studio and create a project and use the Epicor libraries to access its Business Objects (BOs). So, for instance the Part could be accessed by including the library Epicor.Mfg.Part and newing up a Part object. Then it was easy to get information for a part by calling `Part.GetByID("partnum");`. This would return a PartDataSet.

It is different but not so difficult to do the same thing in Epicor 10. However, I have noticed that the PartDataSet does not contain any UD fields, even UD fields that have been properly set up in Epicor10.

How can the UD fields be accessed when tapping into Epicor 10 through its business objects?

EDIT:

```
using Erp.BO;
using Erp.Proxy.BO;

// ...

var binding = Epicor.ServiceModel.StandardBindings.NetTcp.UsernameWindowsChannel();

var cc = new ClientCredentials();
var cred = cc.UserName;
cred.UserName = "****";
cred.Password = "****";
DnsEndpointIdentity ep = new DnsEndpointIdentity("****");

var quoteBo = new QuoteImpl(binding, new Uri("net.tcp://****/Erp/BO/Quote.svc"), cc, ep);

var qds = new QuoteDataSet();
var hed = qds.QuoteHed.NewQuoteHedRow(); // type: QuoteDataSet.QuoteHedRow

// I am not getting UserDefinedColumns as a member of hed.
// This gives me a compiler error.
qds.QuoteHed[0].UserDefinedColumns["Custom_c"] = "value";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is still fairly easy, the DS returned by the call to the BO will be defined in the contract DLL found on both the client and the server, as this file needs to be distributed to the client machines the UD fields are not added to it. It would cause too many client updates.

This means the Visual Studio cannot look at the contract assembly to determine the field names. Instead, you access the field using the columnName indexer i.e:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Hard-coded LogOn method 
        // Reference: Ice.Core.Session.dll
        Ice.Core.Session session = new Ice.Core.Session("manager", "manager", "net.tcp://AppServer/MyCustomerAppserver-99999-10.0.700.2");

        // References: Epicor.ServiceModel.dll, Erp.Contracts.BO.ABCCode.dll
        var abcCodeBO = Ice.Lib.Framework.WCFServiceSupport.CreateImpl<Erp.Proxy.BO.ABCCodeImpl>(session, Erp.Proxy.BO.ABCCodeImpl.UriPath);

        // Call the BO methods
        var ds = abcCodeBO.GetByID("A");
        var row = ds.ABCCode[0];

        System.Console.WriteLine("CountFreq is {0}", row.CountFreq);
        System.Console.WriteLine("CustomField_c is {0}", row["CustomField_c"]);
        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

`UserDefinedColumns` is defined in Epicor.ServiceModel but is inaccessible as it is an internal property of `Ice.IceRow` which `Erp.Tablesets.QuoteHedRow` inherits from.

Comment: You are using Erp.Tablesets.QuoteHedRow. I am trying to use Erp.BO.QuoteDataSet.QuoteHedRow. As far as I can tell, the QuoteImpl class needs a reference whose type matches the latter. Is there a way to cast Tablesets into DataSets (or vice versa)? Is there a different BO object I should be using that communicates using Tablesets?

Comment: I've added a much fuller example for calling a BO method from an external client. You don't need to work with the QuoteImpl class, just call the CreateImpl method and you get a BO instance just as you would if you had called Ice.Assemblies.ServiceRenderer.GetService within a BPM.

Comment: This is perfect. Exactly what I needed. Thanks. I wish I knew a way to utilize the tablesets in an external environment. I tried casting QuoteImpl to QuoteSvcContract, but that didn't work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

When you've found the specific record your looking for and have an object containing all of the columns for the record you should see an additional object named UserDefinedColumns.  It works like a dictonary that is of type `<string, object>`.  So for instance to set a value out you would do something like this:

```
myPartDs.Part[0].UserDefinedColumns["MyUdColumn_c"] = "some value";
```

If you need to pull a value out then you will have to parse it to whatever type it needs to be because they are stored as objects.

Comment: Is there an assembly required to access UserDefinedColumns? I cannot find it on the DataSet. I edited my question above to show which objects and assemblies I am using.